# Сериализация в C#,как сериализировать и десериализировать объекты в xml-файл

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Как реализовать чтение и запись данных в xml файл? В первом файле должна храниться информация о пользователе, а во втором - список друзей каждого пользователя в виде ссылок на пользователей из первого документа.

Вот какой должна быть структура xml документов:

Первый документ:

```
<allUsers>
  <user Id="1">
     <Name>Natali</Name>
  </user>
  <user Id="2">
     <Name>Tom</Name>
  </user>
```

И второй документ:

```
<allUsers>
   <user Id="1">
      <friends>
         <user Id="2"/>
         <user Id="3"/> 
      </friends> 
   </user>
   <user Id="2">
      <friends>
         <user Id="1"/>
         <user Id="3"/> 
      </friends> 
   </user>
</allUsers>
```

А если сделать вот такую ​​структуру документа

```
<allUsers>
  <user Id="1">
     <Name>Natali</Name>
     <friends>
         <user Id="2"/>
         <user Id="3"/> 
      </friends>
  </user>
  <user Id="2">
     <Name>Tom</Name>
     <friends>
         <user Id="1"/>
         <user Id="3"/> 
      </friends>
  </user>
```

то как тогда правильно сериализировать данные в документ и десериализировать документ ( извлечь нужные данные ), если позже нужно будет работать с данными этого документа?

Comment: А является ли `Id` полем в классе, представляющем пользователя, или `Id` существует только в сериализованном варианте?

Comment: да, Id и  Name является полем в классе, представляющем пользователя

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

У вас немного странные требования — обычно список объектов хранится вместе, а не по кускам. Вот что у меня получилось:

Класс с пользователем:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Friends { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

Сериализация списка. Сериализация идёт в два потока (хоть файловых, хоть в память). Для сериализации использользован `XDocument`.

```
void SerializeUsers(List<User> userList, Stream baseStream, Stream connectionStream)
{
    var doc1 =
        new XDocument(
            new XElement("allUsers",
                userList.Select(SerializeUserWithName)));
    doc1.Save(baseStream);
    var doc2 =
        new XDocument(
            new XElement("allUsers",
                userList.Select(SerializeUserWithFriendIds)));
    doc2.Save(connectionStream);
}

XElement SerializeUserWithName(User user)
{
    return
        new XElement("user",
            new XAttribute("Id", user.Id),
            new XElement("Name", user.Name));
}

XElement SerializeUserWithFriendIds(User user)
{
    return
        new XElement("user",
            new XAttribute("Id", user.Id),
            new XElement("friends",
                user.Friends.Select(friend =>
                    new XElement("user", new XAttribute("Id", friend.Id)))));
}
```

Теперь, десериализация. Она немного хитрее, в два этапа.

```
List<User> DeserializeUsers(Stream baseStream, Stream connectionStream)
{
    var doc1 = XDocument.Load(baseStream);
    var allUsers = doc1.Element("allUsers")
                       .Elements("user")
                       .Select(DeserializeUserWithName)
                       .ToList();

    var doc2 = XDocument.Load(connectionStream);
    var userConnections = ExtractConnections(doc2.Element("allUsers").Elements("user"));

    var userById = allUsers.ToDictionary(user => user.Id);
    foreach (var user in allUsers)
    {
        var friendIds = userConnections[user.Id];
        foreach (var friendId in friendIds)
            user.Friends.Add(userById[friendId]);
    }

    return allUsers;
}

Dictionary<int, List<int>> ExtractConnections(IEnumerable<XElement> users)
{
    return users.ToDictionary(
                keySelector: user => (int)user.Attribute("Id"),
                elementSelector: user => user.Element("friends")
                                             .Elements("user")
                                             .Attributes("Id")
                                             .Select(id => (int)id)
                                             .ToList());
}

User DeserializeUserWithName(XElement user)
{
    return new User()
    {
        Id = (int)user.Attribute("Id"),
        Name = (string)user.Element("Name").Value
    };
}
```

И тестовый код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        var user1 = new User() { Id = 1, Name = "Natali" };
        var user2 = new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Tom" };
        var user3 = new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Stackoverflow" };
        user1.Friends.Add(user2);
        user1.Friends.Add(user3);
        user2.Friends.Add(user1);
        user3.Friends.Add(user1);

        var allUsers = new List<User>() { user1, user2, user3 };

        var s1 = new MemoryStream();
        var s2 = new MemoryStream();

        SerializeUsers(allUsers, s1, s2);
        s1.Position = 0;
        s2.Position = 0;

        var allUsers2 = DeserializeUsers(s1, s2);
        // списки allUsers и allUsers2 должны совпадать
    }
}
```

Разбирайтесь.

---

Такой вид сериализации (полностью вручную) довольно хрупок. Возможно, есть более надёжный или правильный путь с XML-сериализацией через атрибуты классов (в этом лучше разбирается @Мстислав Павлов).